# SCSS - incremental property change for styles

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I need to have incremental padding-left for elements, something like this:

```
     .row-group-leaf-indent.row-group-indent-0 {
        padding-left: 25px;
      }

      .row-group-leaf-indent.row-group-indent-1 {
        padding-left: 35px;
      }

      .row-group-leaf-indent.row-group-indent-2 {
        padding-left: 45px;
      }

      .row-group-leaf-indent.row-group-indent-3 {
        padding-left: 55px;
      }
```

I tried to generate this using for loop:

```
      $padding: 15px;
      @for $i from 0 through 9 {
        .row-group-leaf-indent.row-group-indent-(#{$i}) {
          padding-left: $padding + 10px;
        }
      }
```

But I keep getting `Error: Invalid CSS after "...w-group-indent-": expected selector, was "(0)"`  error. Is this supported and my syntax is off or this is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I got to the solution, there were minor changes to the original solution.

```
      $padding: 25px;
      @for $i from 0 through 9 {
        .ag-row-group-leaf-indent.ag-row-group-indent-#{$i} {
          padding-left: ($padding+($i*10));
        }
      }
```